# Problem getting a new token after expiry time lapses in token-based authentication in Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, authentication, access-token

Working on a Laravel application whereby I am performing authentication to an API that requires token to be passed during login and subsequent requests must be passed using a token. The login logic is working fine.

I am having a problem implementing a functionality whereby after the expiry time lapses the user should be redirected to login page to login again so that a new token is issued.

~ Please assist?

**Login Logic**

```
public function login(Request $request){ 
    try {

        $username = $request['user'];
        $access_type = GeneralHelper::checkInput($username);

        //Data to the passed to the API
        $data = array(
            $access_type => $username,
            'password' => $request['password'],
            'login_type' => $access_type,
            'access_type' => 'web',
        );

        //Hit teh API and get a response
        $loginstatus = GeneralHelper::login_Curl($data, 'api/v1/auth/login');

        //Get the response which is success in this case
        $res_status = $loginstatus->status;

        //If suucess is true put some data in a session
        if ($res_status == 'success') {
            Session::put('user', $loginstatus->data->user);
            Session::put('access_token', $loginstatus->data->access_token);
            Session::put('refresh_token', $loginstatus->data->refresh_token);
            Session::put('expiry', $loginstatus->data->expires_in);

        } elseif ($res_status == 'failure') {
            return redirect('/login')->with('error', $loginstatus->message);
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return $e->getMessage() . "\n at LINE " . $e->getLine();
    }

}
```

**Function to check the if token is available**

```
 public function checkAccessToken(){
        //Return true if token is available
        if(!is_null(session('access_token'))){
            return true;
        }
        else {
             return false;
        }
    }
```

**Sample Response am getting from the API after hitting it**

```
{
    "request_time": "2018-12-10 13:36:19",
    "response_time": "2018-12-10 13:36:19",
    "status": "success",
    "message": "login",
    "data": {
        "token_type": "Bearer",
        "expires_in": 3600,
        "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUz******************",
        "refresh_token": "def5020018e6345ab78d32*********************",
        "isAgent": true,
        "user": {
            "firstname": "*************",
            "middlename": "*************",
            "surname": "************",
            "phone": "25***********",
            "email": "*************",
            "tax_id": "************",
            "passport_no": null,
            "national_id": "***********",
            "dob": null
        }
    }
}
```

**checkAccessToken function**

```
public function getLifePolicies(){
        if(!$this->checkAccessToken()){
            return redirect('/')->with('error','Your session has expired. Please Login again');
        }

        else{
            //Perform other action

        }
    }
```

Comment: Where are you using the `checkAccessToken()` function in your code? Also, what version of laravel are you using?

Comment: @thisiskelvin Am using Laravel 5.4 version,, I have edited my question and added the place am calling **checkAccessToken**

Comment: now where is `getLifePolicies()` called?

Comment: @thisiskelvin Basically getLifePolicies() functio is used to load some data to a view but inside it I want to 1st check if the token is valid before redirecting. The problem is am unable to check the expiry of the token and get a new refresh token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am having a problem implementing a functionality whereby after the expiry time lapses the user should be redirected to login page to login again so that a new token is issued.

When you do `if elseif` block you need to do instead a `if else` block so that you always reach the redirection to the login page.

```
//If suucess is true put some data in a session
if ($res_status === 'success') {
    Session::put('user', $loginstatus->data->user);
    Session::put('access_token', $loginstatus->data->access_token);
    Session::put('refresh_token', $loginstatus->data->refresh_token);
    Session::put('expiry', $loginstatus->data->expires_in);

} else {
    return redirect('/login')->with('error', $loginstatus->message);
}
```

**Best practice note**

Always use strict comparison in PHP `===` instead of weak comparison `==`.

**Security Note**

From a security point of view this is not recommended:

```
return $e->getMessage() . "\n at LINE " . $e->getLine();
```

The `$e->getMessage()` may reveal sensitive information about your application.
Instead you should log that information and return a generic phrase that does not leak any potential information to a potential attacker.